# execute java code with package and import

Tags: java

I have a java file with some methods and a test file that tests the methods of the previous file. 
The files are organized as follows (in bold there are the directory, in emphasis the java files):

- **lab**

  - **lastname**

    - **es1**

      - **src**

        - *A.java*
      - **test**

        - *ATest.java*

*A.java* has this package: ***package lastname.es1.src;***

*ATest.java* has this package: ***package lastname.es1.test;***
*ATest.java* has this import: ***import lastname.es1.src.A;***

To compile A.java I position in the **lab** directory and then I write on prompt:

> > javac lastname/es1/src/A.java

To execute ATest.java I position in the **lab** directory and then I write on prompt:

> > java lastname/es1/test/ATest.java

but there is this problem:

> > Error: Could not find or load main class lastname.es1.test.ATest

I feel like an idiot but do not know how to solve. Can anyone help me? 
Thanks

Comment: You need to compile the test as well. You need to pass the test file to javac then you would run java <path_to_class_file>/ATest.class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this

```
java -cp . lastname.es1.test.ATest
```

Assuming you have compiled your ATest.java

```
javac lastname/es1/test/ATest.java
```

Comment: @user3425699 `-cp` is to specify the [classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29).

Comment: Thank you, so write **-cp** or **-classpath** is the same thing?

Comment: That's correct. Also could use the environment variable CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 0):

You never compiled ATest.java, just A.java

Along with:

`javac lastname/es1/src/A.java`

You also have to compile ATest.java:

`javac lastname/es1/test/ATest.java`